# `smartctl` and `smartd` commands not working

Tags: hard-disk, syslog, error-handling, smartctl, smartmontools

I have been receiving hard disk warnings from the smartd daemon for a while now (every 24 hours), saying that my error logs have increased. I have been trying to examine this by checking my log files, but I haven't found anything. The error logs are for my hard disk `/dev/nvme0`. I've been trying to find out what this problem is and have been trying to scan my hard disk using `smartctl` or `smartd` command, but I keep getting back `command not found`. I have the packages installed and I even can open the manual pages; `man smartctl` and `man smartd`. How can I resolve this issue?

The warning I receive is the following:

[image]

Comment: did you try `sudo smartctl` or `sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl`?

Comment: @stoney The latter worked! Thank you. Do you know how I can make it work without having to give the whole path?

Comment: Look in `/etc/sudoers` and adjust `secure_path`